# Unity, When i tried to update my app on my phone android(without play store), it was installed as new app. How to keep the same id?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I did not change Company or Product name.

That happened because i copied my project and opened it as a new project to have a backup

Answer (score 0):

You should give it the same package name in player build settings :
[image]

Comment: thx for the answer, it is the same Package Name and the funny thing is that when i install my old version (after deleting it) it update my new version. But all the saved files are gone.